# jQuery mouseover doesn't work in slideshow with setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, autoplay

I made a little slideshow for my website in Wordpress. I add an autoplay but I want it stops when I hover with the mouse.
I tried but doesn't work.

```
var int = setInterval(function(){ $('#right').click(); }, 1000);
$('#slide-window').mouseover(function(){
    clearInterval(int);
}).mouseout(function(){
    int = setInterval(function(){ $('#right').click(); }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Can you create a working example? With JSfiddle or codepen?

Comment: On codepen it works, I think there is a conflict problem with Wordpress...

https://codepen.io/manueldicenso/pen/eqJyXd

Comment: Do you see anything in the console?

Comment: Nothing, it's clear. I'm working in local with flywheel but I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you any further if you can not reproduce the problem.